# how to update a column statically which is a boolean variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud, controllers

```
#controller
# Boolean variable is act 
def update
@item = post.find(params[:id])
-->@item.update_attribute.act=true
      or
-->@item.update_attributes(true.permit(:act))
      or
--> @item.update(act: false)
@item.save
end
```

hi i need a help to update a single attribute 'act' which is Boolean variable by finding the 'id' of that column.
i searched so many webpages but did not find it how to update statically.

Comment: simply @item.update_attribute("act", true)

Comment: thank you but its not working @Debadatt

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@item.update_attribute :act, true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@item.update_attributes(:act => true)
```

Or

```
@item.act = true
@item.save
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Having it as a boolean variable, this will work:

```
@item.update_attribute(:act, 'true')
```

Also, make sure that you have a member boolean item otherwise you will get an exception if you use it as a link as:

```
undefined method `act?' for nil:NilClass
```

This should be like this in routes.rb:

```
resources :post do
  put :act, on: :member
end
```